# Map Side join fails with return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.mr.MapredLocalTask

Tags: hadoop, join, hive, hiveql

I am trying to perform map-side joins in hive, but it keeps failing with the following message

> FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.mr.MapredLocalTask

The queries that I run are as follows

```
set hive.auto.convert.join=true;
select a.customer_id , b.order_id from customers_sample a JOIN orders_map b on a.customer_id=b.order_customer_id;
```

I am trying these queries in cloudera-quickstart-vm-5.12.0

Could someone please help me with what's missing here.